# A class has 6 men and 4 women and they are ranked among themselves then how many different rankings are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A class has $6$ men and $4$ women and they are ranked among themselves; how many different rankings are possible?

**My solution:**
Possible rankings among men = $6!$
Possible rankings among women = $4!$
Then the total number of possible rankings is $6! + 4!$

But the book in which I am reading says that the total number of possible rankings is $6!\cdot 4!$

Which one is the right answer? And if second one is right then how exactly?

Comment: The book is right. Try it out with brute force on e.g. the smaller numbers 2 and 3 (8 orders or 12 orders?). This to train your intuition.

Comment: @drhab thanks for the response. My confusion was stemmed from following statement: `if r experiments are performed such that the first one result in any m outcomes and for each m possible outcomes there are n possible outcomes of second experiment. Then there are m.n possible outcomes`. From the above statement it felt there has to be a relation between two outcomes. But for men and women ranking among themselves feel like two independent experiments.

Comment: But I understood the concept after trying the solution at smaller scale. For a class of 10, 6 men and 4 women there can be either one of 6 men at each rank or 4 women at each rank for 10 different ranks. Thus if the ranks are to be decided among themselves it would be (6!)(4!)

Comment: $6!4!$ is correct if *"ranked among themselves"* means men and women are ranked separately. But why should this be so, each of ten persons has a distinct identity, so my answer would be $10!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write, there are $6!$ possible rankings for men and $4!$ for women.
To get the total you can't just add the two results.

Think about how you would count one by one.

You first choose one possible ranking for the men, and they count the $4!$ possibilities for women. You already have $4!$ possibilities.

Then you take the next possible ranking for the men, and you do the same : you have already $2.4!$ possilities.

...

And you do this $6!$ times.

So you have $(4!)(6!)$ possibilities.

Hope it helped